# Environment Variables defined in /etc/environment only show for root, not home user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, docker-compose

I'm fairly new to linux and am setting up a server running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I've defined a few environment variable in /etc/environment for use in my docker-compose.yml file. I added the variables to the /etc/environment file, formatted as shown below.

```
PUID=XXXX
PGID=XXX
TZ="America/REGION"
USERDIR="/home/USER_NAME"
```

However, it seems that only the root user, and not the home user can see these variables. When I use *printenv* as the home user these variables don't show up, however they do show up using sudo or as the root user. I thought that when a environment variable was defined in /etc/environment that it should be accessible to all users, but it seems that this isn't the case or that something is going wrong. This is causing problems when trying to access these environment variables in my docker-compose.yml file, as on startup it can't access these variables. I'm not sure how to get these variables to show up to users other than root. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you log in as the other users the same way as you log in as root?

Comment: running `man environment.d`

       `Configuration files in the environment.d/ directories contain lists of environment variable assignments for services started by the systemd user instance.`

also `For backwards compatibility, a symlink to /etc/environment is installed, so this file is also parsed.` so, it seems `/etc/environment` isn't what you think it is - i.e. there's no reason a root login should get those variables - unless your root login specifically refers to that file in `.profile` perhaps

Comment: I think your right that /etc/environment is not used in this way. I was following an outdated guide that was probably using a different distro as well. Anyways, I've put these environment variables in a .env file in the directory I'm using them and now things are working. Thanks for the replies!